# change BIND DNS response using iptables data

Tags: dns, routing, iptables, bind, iproute2

I have BIND DNS server configured with two views. both have different set of zone data. when end user querying the DNS server I need to dynamically route and change his request according to his needs. as an example if user type example.com I need him to give DNS answer 1.2.3.4 if user want to reach different  service and I have to give him DNS response  4.3.2.1 for the same example.com.

afaik only way to do this using matching the users source IP address and route DNS traffic according to that. for setup that I set two virtual interfaces with private IP address and configure bind views to match those internal IP's using match client option

```
view "VIEW1" {
    match-clients { 192.168.10.20; };
    include "/etc/zones2.conf";
};

view "VIEW2" {
    match-clients { 192.168.10.30; };
    include "/etc/zones3.conf";
};
```

I need to achieve results like this

```
scenario 1 --> example.com --> SNAT to 10.20 -->  response (1.2.3.4) --> send back to client 
scenario 2 --> example.com --> SNAT to 10.30 -->  response (4.3.2.1) --> send back to client
```

I need to change incoming packet source address to these private IP address and query using bind DNS  under different views. and send the DNS result back to the client. is this possible to do with ipsets , iptables and iproute ? if yes how can I achieve this ?.

Comment: Is this intended for public use, or are you trying to solve a niche internal problem?  Put another way, are you trying to find a way to solve the problem where Bob.User who uses AOL.com browses to example.com and gets first 1.2.3.4 as the IP address, and then browses to example.com under slightly different circumstances and gets 4.3.2.1?  Or do you control both the client and the server?  Last of all, why do you want to do this (what is your end goal)?

Comment: this is only for internal use and for some testing purpose. yes I need to dynamically change the DNS response when client use the same DNS server IP. I only control server

Comment: Without a very clear example added in the question, there's no way to give an answer. You really need to put a simple use case example, by editing the question, and telling under what circumstance the query would receive 1.2.3.4 and under what other circumstance the very same query would receive 4.3.2.1 . This will then be a creterion to use for any possible solution